# Cannot debug 'subscripted assignments mismatch' error on Matlab loop

Tags: matlab, loops, debugging, math

Below I provide the parameters which essentially set my problem up:

```
%% Parameters

L = 5; % size of domain 
T = 5; % measurement time
dx = 1e-2; % position step
dt = 1e-3; % time step
x0 = 0;

%% More Parameters

t = 0:dt:T; % time vector
x = (0:dx:L)'; % position vector
nt = length(t);
nx = length(x);
mu = dt/dx;
eta = dx/dx;
Lx = (1/dx^2)*spdiags(ones(nx,1)*[1 -2 1],-1:1,nx,nx); % discrete Laplace operator
B = spdiags(ones(nt,1)*[-eta 1+eta 0],0:1,nt-1,nt);
phi = @(x) (x>0).*exp(-1./x.^2);
R = @(x) phi(x).*phi(1-x);
r = R(x-2); 

%% Get Data

u = zeros(nx,nt); % preallocate memory
% initial conditions
u(:,1) = sinc((x-x0)/dx);
u(:,2) = sinc((x-x0)/dx);
for k = 2:nt-1
   u(:,k+1) = 2*u(:,k) - u(:,k-1) + dt^2*Lx*u(:,k) - dt^2*r.*u(:,k);
end

data = u(x==x0,:);
```

Okay, so now that we have what we need, I can describe my problem. Below I am trying to compute a loop which will get us `v`, a 5000x501 matrix, as one can see in the preallocation in the memory. However, the problem is that when I run the loop below, I immediately get the 'subscripted assignments mismatch' error.

```
%% Solve

v = zeros(nx,nt-1); % preallocate memory
v(1,:) = 2*gradient(data); % initial condition
for l = 1:nx
    v(l+1,:) = B*v(l,:);
end
```

I have computed `size(v) = 501 5000`, `size(B) = 5000 50001`, `size(v(l,:)) = size(v(1,:)) = 1 5000`, thus, since `nx = 500`, it should all work; but for some reason it doesn't.

Comment: `B*v(l,:)` will give you an `Inner matrix dimensions must agree` error. What line does the `subscripted assignments mismatch` error occur on?

Comment: @gnovice The error occurs on the line where we have `v(l+1,:) = B*v(l,:);`

Comment: @flawr Well, `B` has 501 rows and 5000 columns, thus performing the loop for `l = 1:nx` should produce a RHS which also has 501 rows since `nx = 501`.

Comment: `*` does matrix multiplication. Since `B` is 5000-by-5001 and `v(l,:)` is 1-by-5000, that won't work. Something isn't right there.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is occurring before the loop, on the following line:

```
v(1,:) = 2*gradient(data); % initial condition
```

The left hand side is 1-by-5000, but the right hand side is 1-by-5001.

Even if you fix that, you're going to run into a problem in the loop due to the `B*v(l,:)` operation:

```
>> B*v(l,:)
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

This is because [matrix multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) requires that the second dimension of `B` (which is 5001) has to be equal to the first dimension of `v(l,:)` (which is 1). You'll also have to make sure that the result is a row vector since it's being assigned to `v(l+1,:)`.